# Why should lambda argument be moved out of parentheses?

Tags: kotlin, conventions

Kotlin coding conventions (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#lambdas) say:
"If a call takes a single lambda, pass it outside of parentheses whenever possible."

What is the reason for this recommendation? Personally it strikes me as a confusing special-casing resulting in an ugly code but I imagine there might be a good reason for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, it is simply a recommendation because it makes the code easier to read (in JetBrains' people opinion and in my opinion as well). Your code would also work but it becomes harder to read.

```kotlin
val list = emptyList<Int>()
list.filter { it > 10 }  // no parentheses
list.filter({it > 10})   // with parentheses and harder to read
```

Below you can see the result of the "Inspect code" action on IntelliJ when you have something like the code above. It is clearly only a style "issue".
[image]

Comment: If lambda is the only parameter it's reasonably readable (in my opinion) but when there is a single lambda that's not the only argument it becomes, well, not great. `someFn(someParam, someOtherParam) { it > 10 }`. Do you have a reference to some official Intelij communication that it's purely about their sense of readability?

Comment: Not an official communication, but I've added an image to my answer that proves it is simply a style issue.

Comment: Aside from most people considering it much easier to read with the lambda outside the parentheses, it (1) Reduces the number of closing parentheses/braces you have to keep track of as you're writing code. Often a lambda has nested code inside it, which makes this important. Since Kotlin has inline functions and scope functions, it is much more common to have multi-line lambdas than in Java. (2) This style permits DSL-like code to be written. Better to stick with a single convention everywhere if it's going to be used in these cases anyway.

Comment: Regarding the case where there are other parameters in front of it, I think you'll find as you work with Kotlin code more that it makes a lot of sense. It makes it look kind of like a function that you pass parameters to, and that is so often kind of what you are doing with a higher-order function with multiple parameters. "With these things, do this." If you had to include a multi-line lambda inside the parentheses, there would be no pretty solution to where you should open the braces and close them. It looks not great to you now only because it's new to you.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm coming from Python where lambdas are commonplace but indeed not multi-line. Not that it's not possible, matter of style: I'd consider it clearer to define a named function if it's not fitting on 1 line, rather than try to make it fit in a parameter list. Well, anyway, when in Rome do as Romans do. Maybe I'll come to like it; good to try a new approach.